# How to let typescript understand the existence of static members that are dynamically added to a class?

Tags: typescript

I've got a `QueryBuilder` and would like to present all its methods as static member on the `Model` class.

Apparently, It's valid Javascript code. However, how could I let typescript understand the existence of those static methods on `Model`?

```
function queryable (target: any) {
  for (const prop in target.prototype.builder) {
    if (prop === 'constructor' || target.prototype.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      continue;
    }
    target[prop] = (...args: any[]): any => {
      return target.prototype.builder[prop](...args);
    };
  }
}

class QueryBuilder {
  where(prop: string, value: string) {
    console.log(prop, value);
    console.log("I've presented on model class as static method.");
  }
  // ...
}

@queryable
class Model {
  get builder () {
    return new QueryBuilder();
  }
  // ...
}


// calling static where
Model.where('color', 'red');
```

> Property 'where' does not exist on type 'typeof Model'.

See in [**Typescript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true&target=1#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)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you should keep an eye on is [TypeScript#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) but as of currently (3.5.1) a *decorator* can't change the type of the class it is decorating.

That being said you can still define the decorator in the same fashion but call it explicitly rather than as a decorator, as many typescript projects using redux's popular `connect` decorator have to do.

```
class _Model {
  get builder () {
    return new QueryBuilder();
  }

  // ...
}
const Model = queryable(_Model);
```

or if it is the main export of a module you can get away with one name:

```
class Model {
  get builder () {
    return new QueryBuilder();
  }

  // ...
}
export default queryable(Model);
```

Then the trick is to better annotate the decorator to teach typescript all the additions `queryable` has made to it's `target`:

```
function queryable<T extends new (...args: any[]) => {builder: any}>(target: T): InstanceType<T>['builder'] & (typeof target) {
  for (const prop in target.prototype.builder) {
    if (prop === 'constructor' || target.prototype.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      continue;
    }
    (target as any)[prop] = (...args: any[]): any => {
      return target.prototype.builder[prop](...args);
    };
  }
  return target as any
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true&target=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABARxAUwE4E8CGAjAGzQB4AVRNADyjTABMBnRMNAd0QAoA6HnDAcwYAuRDjBYA2gF0AlIgC8APkQBvPCBgE6mEWKwBfRRyh9+aKCNIyRASTAMTkNKSwAHEqUUSA5Os3aMbylEADJOKDc0OGBEEwFzORUAWAAoRERgOAxOCAQHRFcMOFdEGCQ4syguQrgoWsiuPy1MRNT09JgYjhqS+T7Eb1z7KAwQaCzvRAAfKdjTc2qiuoj3LgALHAYAeVYwAAUi9wwI7sOZVrT29KHYMHQAbjb2-Sf043moUSY9GQke4PknB4XFMwlE4mk1nBWAUymSlyuGHMIAw5Q+i1q9VWTQCf0OUm4vAEDBkjwRiH0ZPSL0uSKgKLR8U+m2hqRpqQgBE2TAAiuhsAAhDTNbLw9KsNaYNCnYoiBwYMr8AA0iAAbjgCOg5SNFRcrkMGHAiFwCHB+DLXCr1Zq0KTXogDUa0CazRwAEQ2byqtAFJEMWg0OiIBCIAC2cG0BAdXIY3yYDhwsAgYfMawjXDddsuNPZKU53MQAH0ALIRtBRsWISqIHGYDh69p0hnMNiIPmYLBC-x1rPU1JPAD0A8QwLZHLyn1LkYUKH5uEI0pLZYIWdSQ4dGoIisQCaTiAlUtSU-LXAPSI4gyNExV3iRdG8pKAA)

Comment: Good point. I don't mind explicit implementation. However, in reality, `Model` class also accepts a type i.e. `class Model<T> extends ...`, I was wondering how this situation could be resolved in your example where `queryable(Model)` is being called?

Comment: That should be no problem. The type of the parameter is simply a class with a builder property. The return type says it is the same class plus the builder fields.

Comment: +1. So, addressing my original question here, to help Typescript understand dynamically added static members would be a connector like `const connect = <T extends new () => {builder: any}>(target: T): 
  InstanceType<T>['builder'] & (typeof target) => target;` and then `const Model = connect(OriginalModel);`

Answer (score 0):

Since Typescript is a strong typing language it always checks if type usage matches type interface. This checking takes place during transpilation, when Typescript has no idea you're going to add a new method. Because you add it in run-time. The only way to call such a method is casting to something general like `any`:

```
(<any>Model).where('color', 'red');
```

It's like you're saying to Typescript that you're sure about method existence and transpiller shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks mate. That's a workaround to get rid of error but I'd rather not to cast but mutate the target.